# identity inspector doesn't show choices for connecting a class to tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios5, interface-builder

I added a tableviewcontroller to my story board.  I have two regular viewcontrollers currently and i've been able to in the identity inspector go to custom class, click the down arrow next to the class name there, then select from classes in the project to connect a class. With this tableviewcontroller, it just shows Class:UITableViewController with no other choices in the drop down. Is this normal for table view controllers? This is my first time working with one and i'll be learning as I go this morning.

I did try typing in the name of my custom tableviewcontroller class and while it accepted the name i can tell it's not working. i added to view did load of this custom class,

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

and that didn't seem to do anything.  I also changed number of rows returned to 4 and that didn't seem to do anything.

I am loading it with the associated view controller i created.

```
ChannelColorsTableViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChannelColors"];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

thanks
Mike

Comment: Is the superclass of `ChannelColorsTableViewController` `UITableViewController`?

Comment: yes. i tried to look at possible classes before creating my custom class. Then it occurred to me only classes that inherited from UITableViewController would show and i better create my custom class first but it still didn't show.

Comment: It's working now.  This must have been it. Until i created a table view controller class it wouldn't show. I created it and it didn't appear to show but now it is so maybe there was some delay or i didn't notice it but its working.

Comment: If you've found the solution to this, you should consider writing it up as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I added a tableviewcontroller to the story board but when i created my class I made a mistake and it was inheriting from tableview.